# pyfinance dividends and documentation

Tags: python, finance

I'm trying to use pyfinance to pull data, I have run into issues with the dividends. Below is the code, the error I et is:

```
    import yfinance as yf

print('Enter Ticker:')
symbol = input()
symbol = yf.Ticker(symbol)
print('Forward PE:')
print(symbol.info['forwardPE'])
print('Dividends:')

info = yf.Ticker(symbol).info
div = info.get('trailingAnnualDividendYield')
print(div)
```

Does anyone have documentation for pyfinance? What I have been able to find is slim, how can I view the modules/classes/etc

Error from python interpreter:

```
    Enter Ticker:
c
Forward PE:
8.224477
Dividends:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    info = yf.Ticker(symbol).info
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yfinance/base.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.ticker = ticker.upper()
AttributeError: 'Ticker' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

Comment: For documentation see (https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance)

Answer (score 0):

You assign `symbol = yf.Ticker(symbol)`, so `symbol` is `yfinance.Ticker object` now, not a string. And then you call `yf.Ticker(symbol).info` (which is not needed) that leads to an error. Don't save on variables names.

```
import yfinance as yf

print('Enter Ticker:')
symbol = input()
s = yf.Ticker(symbol)
print('Forward PE:')
print(s.info['forwardPE'])
print('Dividends:')

div = s.info.get('trailingAnnualDividendYield')
print(div)
```

And the results:

```
Enter Ticker:
ibm
Forward PE:
12.553453
Dividends:
0.049131215
```

Comment: what is it that I did in my recent reply? I'm new to python. I was able to fix it with symbol =x

Answer (score -1):

This fixed it:

```
import yfinance as yf

print('Enter Ticker:')
x = input()
symbol = x
symbol = yf.Ticker(symbol)
info = yf.Ticker(x).info
div = info.get('trailingAnnualDividendYield')

print('Forward PE:')
print(symbol.info['forwardPE'])
print('Dividend:')
print(div)
```

Comment: You do need to call `yf.Ticker(x)` for the second time, `info = symbol.info` is enough. Also please check if my answer has answered your question.

Comment: Why even call `Ticker` twice? And why use `x`? Why not just `info = symbol.info`?